# Internet Explorer gzip/deflate

Tags: internet-explorer, gzip, deflate

I have problem) send from server(apache) binary file, compressed it, content-encoding set in 'gzip' - some machine with IE-it works, another - doesn't(IE are same version), change on 'deflate' - works where didn't worked,but where worked - doesn't, System are same too. Thanks

Comment: that's really strange, thse modile gzip and deflate is done on web server/server/apache level. have you tried this on firefox or chrome? if its just IE that's doing that I wouldn't worry about it, its a terrible browser and the versions are inconsistent.

Comment: @unixmiah,in case of another browsers it works with 'deflate', what about IE - have found this-http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837251 right now, maybe problem in it, tomorrow I'll try set this update and see

Comment: there you go, your solution is to download the Q837251.exe package or follow the workaround. you'll need to do it on all the IE browsers. if you're serving public, which is tough, maybe leave a note and link to the ms support site for ie add-on and the work around.

Comment: @PetroTrushin Please install all available updates through Windows Update. I work on the Internet Explorer team and would like to know if this resolves your issue(s). If not, we can work on getting a repro constructed and I will escalate further.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, ok, but what about update, IE which works with 'deflate'-almost last, maybe 3-4 month without update, one that works with 'gzip'-old

Comment: @PetroTrushin Updates are generally good just in case we have a regression (not common, but technically possible). Do you have a URL that I can access to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, it will be problem with test,sorry,about regression -  i have virtual machine with snapshots(ie8, ie9, ie10, ie11) on which - all work with deflate, and VM with IE8(too late updated) - doesn't work on deflate but good works on gzip, sorry two Vm with old IE8